# Border radius with Box shadow css

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

I have `box-shadow` on form which stretches on whole screen and it worked perfectly until i added `border-radius` to form.

Code:

```
.customer-modal{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px 900px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: whitesmoke;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40vw; 
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

[image]

Code with radius

```
.customer-modal{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 300px 900px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: whitesmoke;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40vw;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 4%;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How can i fix it so box shadow looks as it looked without border-radius?

Comment: maybe use `0` instead of `300px` ?

Comment: but how? what was the reason

Comment: On a side note: Solving the modal overlay using box-shadow probably isn't the best way in the first place, as you can still click on all elements in the background. You'll need to set `pointer-events: none` on everything except all elements inside the modal (see https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/abbEbEy), which may not work in all clients from my experience.

Comment: box-shadow's third property is the blur property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow The larger this value, the bigger the blur, so the shadow becomes bigger and lighter. Negative values are not allowed. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow's edge is sharp). I haven't checked, but I suppose Temani thinks that the effect you're seeing is the blur. As another aside 0px is the same as 0, so just write 0 instead of 0px.

Comment: Try to make black background overlay with `content` property or may be with `outer container` and` inner container `